# Git tool BFG when run with filter excluding, filter does not work on other branches

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

```bash
java -jar bfg.jar --filter-content-excluding '*.{h,cpp,c,xml,js,json,pl,html,htm,py,csv}' --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M --no-blob-protection .git
```

Please help... when run with filter excluding, filter does not work on other branches... excluding files removed in other branches